# How can we check value of a columns of a table are populated or not by using a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Iam asking this because iam very much new to stored procedure. Can any help me in writing a stored procedure for checking whether value of a columns of a table are populated or not by using a stored procedure?

for example:- I have a table named student. it contains 5 columns.in this almost 3 columns have values and other two columns do not have values in it. So by stored procedure how can we do this?

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Comment: What you mean by value of a columns of a table are populated or not?

Comment: Like this? `SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE ColumnName IS NULL `

Comment: @Anuraj:- I mean values as the contents of the columns.

Comment: @Febin, did you try @Simen's response?

Comment: @Lieven:- that i have tried but my requirement is to get the column name or the count of columns whose values are null, that seems to be very complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to get the column names that does not have any values.

```
declare @T table (Col1 int, Col2 int, Col3 int, Col4 int, Col5 int)

insert into @T values (1,    1,    1,    null, null)
insert into @T values (2,    2,    null, null, null)
insert into @T values (3,    null, null, null, null)
insert into @T values (null, null, null, null, null)

select [Column]
from 
  (select
     count(Col1) as Col1,
     count(Col2) as Col2,
     count(Col3) as Col3,
     count(Col4) as Col4,
     count(Col5) as Col5
   from @T) as T
unpivot
   ([Count] for [Column] in 
      (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)
) as unpvt
where [Count] = 0
```

Result

```
Column
------
Col4
Col5
```

Comment: - can we check for the string field as well using this Query

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@@ROWCOUNT (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) to get the number of rows affected by the last statement.

Comment: can i use pivot function in this

Comment: sorry I have not that much idea :( Give a try I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one time check, you could use the output of following script to find tables with columns with only NULL values.

**Script**

```
SELECT  'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ' 
        + so.name
        + ' WHERE '
        + sc.name
        + ' IS NOT NULL) PRINT '''
        + so.name
        + '.'
        + sc.name
        + ''''
FROM    sys.columns sc
        INNER JOIN sys.objects so ON so.object_id = sc.object_id        
WHERE   so.type = 'U'
```

**Results**

```
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column IS NOT NULL) PRINT 'Table.Column'
```